# Creating a conditional loop in Numpy/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops

Absolute newbie here....

I have a dataset with a list of expenses data [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuWLk.jpg)
I would like to create a loop to identify the dates in which the person spends more than the previous day and also spends more than the next day. In doing so, I would like it to either print the date and amount(expenses) or create a new column reading true/false.
Should I use Numpy or Pandas?

I was thinking of something in the likes of: today = i yesterday = i-1 and tomorrow = i+1
...and then proceeding to create a loop

Comment: Copy and paste your date into the question; do not use images.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
# sample data
np.random.seed(4)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-01-10'),
                   'Name': ['Some Name', 'Another Name']*5,
                   'Price': np.random.randint(100,1000, 10)})

# groupby name 
g = df.groupby('Name')['Price']

# create a mask to filter your dataframe where the current price is grater than the price above and below
mask = (g.shift(0) > g.shift(1)) & (g.shift(0) > g.shift(-1))
df[mask]

        Date          Name  Price
3 2020-01-04  Another Name    809
4 2020-01-05     Some Name    997
7 2020-01-08  Another Name    556
```